# Xamarin Forms Shell - change tab color

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I've been playing with the [Xaminals sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs) and for most elements, there is a way to change colors using "Shell." in the XAML. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to change the color of the selected tab *bar* (see screenshot below):

[image]

It's always grey. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This should be done in platform specific renderers [TabbedPageRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/TabbedPageRenderer.cs)

Comment: I guess we have to use a custom renderer? I'll give it a shot and report back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this article: [Xamarin.Forms Shell Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers). Note that this specifically addresses custom renderers for shell.

Here's my code (for Android):

...

```
// Create a custom shell renderer (MyShellRenderer in my case):

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(MyShellRenderer))]
namespace Xaminals.Droid
{
    public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        public MyShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override IShellTabLayoutAppearanceTracker CreateTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(ShellSection shellSection)
        {
            return new MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(this);
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
// Create a custom appearance tracker for tab layout (MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker in my case):

public class MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker : ShellTabLayoutAppearanceTracker
{
    public MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(IShellContext shellContext) : base(shellContext)
    {
    }

    protected override void SetColors(TabLayout tabLayout, Color foreground, Color background, Color title, Color unselected)
    {
        base.SetColors(tabLayout, foreground, background, title, unselected);

        tabLayout.SetSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.Red.ToAndroid());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, you want to change the color of selected tab, you can do this by style. The **ShellTitleColor** is the color for selected color, the **ShellUnselectedColor** is the color for other tab unselected.

```
   <Shell.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" 
           TargetType="Element">
        <Setter Property="Shell.ShellBackgroundColor" 
                Value="#455A64" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.ShellForegroundColor" 
                Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.ShellTitleColor" 
                Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.ShellDisabledColor" 
                Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.ShellUnselectedColor" 
                Value="#95FFFFFF" />
    </Style>

</Shell.Resources>


<FlyoutItem Route="animals"
            Title="Animals"
            FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <Tab Title="Domestic"
         Route="domestic"
         Icon="paw.png">
        <ShellContent Route="cats"
                      Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"
                      Title="Cats"
                      Icon="cat.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Route="dogs"
                      Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"
                      Title="Dogs"
                      Icon="dog.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <ShellContent Route="monkeys"
                  Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"
                  Title="Monkeys"
                  Icon="monkey.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MonkeysPage}" />
    <ShellContent Route="elephants"
                  Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"
                  Title="Elephants"
                  Icon="elephant.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ElephantsPage}" />  
    <ShellContent Route="bears"
                  Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"
                  Title="Bears"
                  Icon="bear.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:BearsPage}" />

    <ShellContent Route="about"
              Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"
              Title="About"
              Icon="info.png"
              ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AboutPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: Apologies. I meant the selected tab *bar* as indicated by the red highlight in my screenshot.

Comment: @karthiect, don't care about my gif, please just set **Shell.ShellTitleColor** property as Red in style , so you can use this style in shell. I have updated my code

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out and there is to need to make any custom renderer and you can simply give it in shellcontent tag

```
<ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" Shell.TabBarTitleColor="#353f7b" Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor="Green" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the style and set the TabBar style to be based on this. I would suggest that you move this out into a resource folder and new file like (TabBarStyles.xaml) and the use merged dictionary to pull in. But here is the code
e.g.

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">White</Color>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.Clip" Value="True" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>

<!-- Your Pages -->
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Home" Icon="account_balance-24px.png" Route="browse">
        <ShellContent Title="A" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MainView}" Route="a"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png" Route="about">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MainView}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```