# Change selected tab background color in .net MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I have a shell navigation menu in the form of a flyout menu where each FlyoutItem contains a TabBar menu in the bottom of the screen. This is done looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs

```
<FlyoutItem Title="FirstFlyout" Icon="flyout_icon.png">
     <Tab Title="FirstTab" Icon="tab_icon.png">
          <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:FirstView}" />
     </Tab>
     <Tab Title="SecondTab" Icon="tab_icon.png">
          <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:SecondView}" />
     </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

I also have a Style to change the appearance of the tabs

```
<Style TargetType="Tab">
    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor"
        Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor"
        Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor"
        Value="Green" />
</Style>
```

My problem is that the TabBarUnselectedColor affects the color of the text on the tab instead of the background, and there does not appear to be any property to control the background color of a selected tab.

How can I set the background color of the currently selected tab?

Comment: You can check this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/66b4b7b4-fbdc-48c0-b2a3-02e5b1c8b09d/how-to-change-selected-tab-background-color-in-tabbedpage-in-xamarinforms?forum=xamarinforms).

Comment: Thanks. Im not sure how this translates to maui though as there is no drawable

Comment: I tested the code you provided, and as you said. You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937585/xamarin-forms-shell-change-tab-color). It's about using custom renderers.

Answer (score 1):

So if you check the documentation you will find what you are looking for :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs#tab-appearance

The Shell class defines the following attached properties that control the appearance of tabs:

- TabBarBackgroundColor, of type Color, that defines the background colour for the tab bar. If the property is unset, the BackgroundColor property value is used.
- TabBarDisabledColor, of type Color, that defines the disabled color for the tab bar. If the property is unset, the DisabledColor property value is used.
- TabBarForegroundColor, of type Color, that defines the foreground color for the tab bar. If the property is unset, the ForegroundColor property value is used.
- TabBarTitleColor, of type Color, that defines the title color for the tab bar. If the property is unset, the TitleColor property value will be used.
  TabBarUnselectedColor, of type Color, that defines the unselected color for the tab bar. If the property is unset, the UnselectedColor property value is used.

For the unselected bg color u need to change the `TabBarDisabledColor`

so your style would look like this

```
<Style TargetType="Tab">
 <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor"
    Value="Blue" />
 <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor"
    Value="White" />
 <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor"
    Value="White" />
 <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarDisabledColor"
    Value="Green" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Did you actually try this, or did you just look at the documentation? It does not work.

Comment: But I can also just design the application around the parts of the framework that is not currently broken. Just changing the text color also looks pretty good I guess.